# “So” or “then” in the conditional mood

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs, confusable

> If she is going to London, **then** I will also go along with her.

> If she is going to London, **so** I will also go along with her.

I think the second one is incorrect. I was taught that we can’t use ‘so’ there but I don’t know why we can’t.

Answer (score 1):

If ... then ... is a standard construction. It does not assume the first part is true, and maybe she does not go to London. In this case I might not go (anywhere) with her.

Using "so" in this position assumes the first part is true. "She is going to London *so* I will also go along with her." The statement says three things - that she is going to London, that I will go with her, and that the first is a reason for the second.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the second one is incorrect. "Then" means the result of a condition, so it's correct. "So" is like "therefore". It's the consequence of something real/true, but an "if" clause isn't real because it's just a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Using "then" is correct, but it can be left unsaid and an immediately ensuing "so" can be part of the "then" clause such that it may come right after the comma at the start of the "then" clause when the "then" in the "then" clause is left unsaid, meaning someone can properly say, for example:

> If she is going to London, so will I.

To be clear, the above example means:

> If she is going to London, then so will I.

It's just that the "then" can be omitted, remaining only implied.

I'm providing this answer because it seems to me that this is what you're driving at, that this is actually the crux of your question.